# Linq Expression tree Any() issue

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

Hello I'm having trouble with an expression tree using the .Any() extension method.

Here's my code:

```
IQueryable<Book> querableBooks = Books.Values.AsQueryable<Book>();

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book), "book");

MemberExpression props = Expression.Property(pe, "properties");

ParameterExpression propList = Expression.Parameter(typeof(List<BookProperty>), "properties");

var _test = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<BookProperty>, bool>>(operation, new ParameterExpression[] { propList });

var _Any = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "any", new Type[] { typeof(BookProperty) }, new Expression[] { propList });

Expression Lamba = Expression.Lambda(_Any, _props);
```

_test returns {properties => ((bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie") And (bookProperty.value == "1"))}

_Any returns {properties.Any()}

Lambda returns {book.properties => properties.Any()}

The Book class is like this:

```
 public class Book : IBook
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
//Removed for clarity
        public List<BookProperty> properties { get; set; }

    }
```

An the BookProperty class:

```
public class BookProperty
    {
        public BookProperty()
        {
            value = "0";
        }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int bookId { get; set; }
        public Book book { get; set; }
        public int typeId { get; set; }
        public BookPropertyType type { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

And BookPropertyType class:

```
 public class BookPropertyType
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string groupe { get; set; }
        public string key { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public int order { get; set; }
        public string editorType { get; set; }
        public string unite { get; set; }
    }
```

So I'm close to it, but I don't how to merge all this correctly to have a query like this

{book.propertie.Any(bookProperty => bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie") And (bookProperty.value == "1")}

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you include the `Book` and `BookProperty` classes.

Comment: @IvanStoev I added the classes. Thank you

Comment: are you looking to get a subset of the Queryable books based on property type and property value? If so what about: queryableBooks.Where(book => book.properties.Any(property => property.type.key == "lingerie" && property.value == "1"))

Comment: @Brino It's exactly what I want to achieve, but with and expression tree and not a fixed request because it will be used to filter books from user choices. So I need it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for expression like this:

```
Expression<Func<Book, bool>> bookPredicate = book => book.properties.Any(
    bookProperty => bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie" && bookProperty.value == "1");
```

You can build it dynamically like this:

```
var book = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Book), "book");
var properties = Expression.PropertyOrField(book, "properties");
var bookProperty = Expression.Parameter(typeof(BookProperty), "bookProperty");
// bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie"
var conditionA = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(Expression.PropertyOrField(bookProperty, "type"), "key"),
    Expression.Constant("lingerie")
);
// bookProperty.value == "1"
var conditionB = Expression.Equal(
    Expression.PropertyOrField(bookProperty, "value"),
    Expression.Constant("1")
);
// bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie" && bookProperty.value == "1"
var condition = Expression.AndAlso(conditionA, conditionB);
// bookProperty => bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie" && bookProperty.value == "1"
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<BookProperty, bool>>(condition, bookProperty);
// book.properties.Any(bookProperty => bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie" && bookProperty.value == "1")
var anyCall = Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { typeof(BookProperty) },
    properties, predicate
);
// book => book.properties.Any(...)
var bookPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Book, bool>>(anyCall, book);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

It works fine. I was able to put it in the wherre call I already done. It works perfectly.

I will clean a bit my code and post the final result .