# How to express .Any(y => y.Name == "val")); within an expression tree?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm trying to create a DbSet LINQ filter.
I'm using expressions so that I can reduce the number of lines of code caused by unique combinations of filter options and filter properties.

I was able to apply this easily for properties of the object  in the DbSest (Working Code pasted bellow). But I hit a road block when I was trying to express. `dbSet.Where(x => x.listProp.Any(y => y.Name == "val"));`
I don't know how to express `.Any(...)` while building an expression tree.

Currently I'm trying to follow the solution in the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470086/linq-expression-tree-any-issue) but I'm getting the following issue when I get to `var anyCall = ...` : `System.InvalidOperationException: 'No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. '`

This is what I currently have.

```
private IQueryable<dbo.Transaction> _FilterTransactionPartyType(ParameterExpression param, IQueryable<Transaction> query, string transactionPartyType)
{

    MemberExpression expM2M = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Parties");

    Type tM2M = typeof(M2M_Transactions_Party);
    ParameterExpression paramM2m = Expression.Parameter(tM2M, "m2m");

    //Any(m2m => m2m.Party.Name == "dd" && m2m.PartyType.Name = "dd")
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piParty = tM2M.GetProperty("Party");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyName = piParty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Name");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyType = tM2M.GetProperty("TransactionPartyType");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyTypeName = piPartyType.PropertyType.GetProperty("Name");

    MemberExpression expPartyType = Expression.Property(paramM2m, piPartyType);
    MemberExpression expPartyTypeName = Expression.Property(expPartyType, piPartyTypeName);

    ConstantExpression expPartyTypeValue = Expression.Constant(transactionPartyType, typeof(string));
    BinaryExpression isPartyTransactionType = Expression.Equal(expPartyTypeName, expPartyTypeValue);

    MemberExpression expParties = Expression.Property(paramM2m, piParty);
    MemberExpression expParty = Expression.Property(expParties, piPartyName);

    BinaryExpression isParty = _Filter(expParty);

    BinaryExpression isPartyAndType = Expression.AndAlso(isParty, isPartyTransactionType);
    Expression<Func<M2M_Transactions_Party, bool>> internalLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<M2M_Transactions_Party, bool>>(isPartyAndType, paramM2m);


    // book.properties.Any(bookProperty => bookProperty.type.key == "lingerie" && bookProperty.value == "1")
    var anyCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Queryable), "Any", new[] { tM2M },
        expM2M, internalLambda
    );
    // book => book.properties.Any(...)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(anyCall, param);

    return query.Where(lambda);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what my issue was.

There was one issue where I had used `typeof(Queryable)` instead of `typeof(Enumerable)` and another issue I identified for anyone looking at my method above is that I was passing `IQueryable` when I should of been just returning `Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>` and concatenating these after using this [post (combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool)

Here is my current method

```
private Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> _FilterTransactionPartyType(ParameterExpression param, string transactionPartyType)
{
    MemberExpression expM2M = Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Parties");

    Type tM2M = typeof(M2M_Transactions_Party);
    ParameterExpression paramM2m = Expression.Parameter(tM2M, "m2m");

    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piParty = tM2M.GetProperty("Party");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyName = piParty.PropertyType.GetProperty("Name");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyType = tM2M.GetProperty("TransactionPartyType");
    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo piPartyTypeName = piPartyType.PropertyType.GetProperty("Name");

    MemberExpression expPartyType = Expression.Property(paramM2m, piPartyType);
    MemberExpression expPartyTypeName = Expression.Property(expPartyType, piPartyTypeName);

    ConstantExpression expPartyTypeValue = Expression.Constant(transactionPartyType, typeof(string));
    BinaryExpression isPartyTransactionType = Expression.Equal(expPartyTypeName, expPartyTypeValue);

    MemberExpression expParties = Expression.Property(paramM2m, piParty);
    MemberExpression expParty = Expression.Property(expParties, piPartyName);

    BinaryExpression isParty = _Filter(expParty);

    BinaryExpression isPartyAndType = Expression.AndAlso(isParty, isPartyTransactionType);
    Expression<Func<M2M_Transactions_Party, bool>> internalLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<M2M_Transactions_Party, bool>>(isPartyAndType, paramM2m);

    MethodCallExpression anyCall = Expression.Call(
        typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new[] { tM2M },
        expM2M, internalLambda
    );

    Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, bool>>(anyCall, param);

    return lambda;
}
```